# Tensor product of two finitely-generated modules over a local ring is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> If $R$ is a local ring and $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated $R$-modules such that $M\otimes N=0$ then how does it follow from Nakayama's lemma that either $M=0$ or $N=0$?

This is an exercise in Atiyah and Macdonald. The part I could not show in the hints is $({M{\otimes}_R N)}_{k}=0$ implies $M_{k}{\otimes }_{k} N_{k}=0$, where $k=R/\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 31):

From $M\otimes_RN=0$ we get $R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R (M\otimes_R N)=0$. Then it follows that $(R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R M)\otimes_{R/\mathfrak m}(R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R N)=0$. But $R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R M\simeq M/\mathfrak mM$ and similarly $R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R N\simeq N/\mathfrak mN$. Since $M/\mathfrak mM$ and $N/\mathfrak mN$ are $R/\mathfrak m$-vector spaces, it follows that $M/\mathfrak mM=0$ or $N/\mathfrak mN=0$, that is, $M=\mathfrak mM$ or $N=\mathfrak mN$, so by Nakayama we have $M=0$ or $N=0$.

**Edit.** For proving $$R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R (M\otimes_R N)\simeq(R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R M)\otimes_{R/\mathfrak m}(R/\mathfrak m\otimes_R N)$$ use the associativity and the following property of tensor product: $L\otimes_SS\simeq L$, where in this case $S=R/\mathfrak m$ and $L=R/\mathfrak m\otimes_RM$.

Comment: I'm looking for a counterexample (with $M$ or $N$ not finitely generated) where the implication $M = 0$ or $N = 0$ does not hold. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: associativity of different tensor product is not true, in that case it is true because the $R/m$ module is bi $(R/m, R)$ module.

Comment: @mathcourse: Take $R = k[\![x]\!]$, $M = k$, $N = \operatorname{Frac}(R)$. Then, $M$ is f.g., $N$ is not, $M \otimes_R N$ is zero because $M$ is torsion.