# $M_{\mathfrak{p}} \otimes_{R_{\mathfrak{p}}} N_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$ implies $M_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$ or $N_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Studying commutative algebra I've found this statement:

> If $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated $R$-modules, with $R$ a commutative ring, and $\mathfrak{p} \subset R $ is a prime ideal, then $M_{\mathfrak{p}} \otimes_{R_{\mathfrak{p}}} N_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$ implies $M_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$ or $N_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$.

Is it true ? Why ?

Comment: @user26857: if you want write an answer

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/321382)