# Other proof for tensor product equal to zero (without use Nakayama lemma and Jacobson radical)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, products

> Let $R$ is commutative local ring, $M$ is $R$-module, $N$ is $R$-module. If $M,N$ are finitely generated, how to prove:
>
> $M \otimes_R N=0$  if and only if $M=0$ or $N=0$.
>
> If we delete the condition (local ring), then is the statement right?

A proof is existed by Nakayama lemma. Suppose $M \otimes_R N=0$, $J$ is maximal ideal in $R$, let $k=\frac{R}{J}$ so $k$ is field. $M_k=M\otimes k=M \otimes \frac{R}{J}=\frac{M}{JM}$.

If we delete the local condition the statement is not true. Example: $(m,n)=1 $ then $\Bbb Z_m \otimes \Bbb Z_n=0 (???)$, $\Bbb Z_m, \Bbb Z_n \not = 0$.

Comment: @user26857 I wrote some proof by nakayama lemma . and Jacobson radical . I want the proof that is not used them , also counterexamples for deleted condition(local ring) I wrote that example but I don't understand that (???)

Comment: @user26857 in other words I don't understand the proof is used nakayama lemma completely.

Comment: For future references, [here is a proof using Nakayama lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321374/tensor-product-of-two-finitely-generated-modules-over-a-local-ring-is-zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the proof: is it clear why $M\otimes_R R/J\simeq M/JM$? If yes, then consider $M\otimes_R N=0$ and tensor it (over $R$) with $R/J$ left *and* right. Then you get $M/JM\otimes_{R/J} N/JN=0$. Thus you have two vector spaces, namely $M/JM$ and $N/JN$, whose tensor product is $0$. But non-zero vector spaces have bases, so their tensor product, and then we have to admit that $M/JM=N/JN=0$. Now is time for Nakayama's lemma to enter the scene.

For the non-local case: $\mathbb Z_m=\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, and using again that $M/IM\simeq M\otimes_R R/I$ we get $\mathbb Z_m\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z_n\simeq\mathbb Z_n/m\mathbb Z_n$. But the last one is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/(m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z)$, and since $m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z=\gcd(m,n)\mathbb Z$ you are done.

Comment: It's Ok . just two problems for me. ***P1***:Why $M/JM\otimes_{R/J} N/JN=0$  ,,,,,,,,,,,,***P2***:Why $\mathbb Z/(m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z)\simeq\mathbb Z_n/m\mathbb Z_n$

Comment: $M/JM\otimes_{R/J}N/JN=(M\otimes_RR/J)\otimes_{R/J}N/JN\simeq M\otimes_R N/JN$. (I've just realized that it's enough to tensor $M\otimes_RN=0$ with $R/J$ only on one side.) Here I've used a property of tensor product like $M\otimes_S S\simeq M$, where $S$ is a ring.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $m(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)=(m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z)/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: upvoted,***P2*** is solved , but why $$(M\otimes_{R} R/J)\otimes_{\frac RJ } \frac{N}{JN}\simeq M \otimes_R \frac{N}{JN}$$

Comment: $(X\otimes_RS)\otimes_SY\simeq X\otimes_R(S\otimes_SY)\simeq X\otimes_RY$ because of the tensor property I've already mention. (Here $S=R/J$, $X=M$ and $Y=N/JN$.)

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the proof. Why you can conclude that $M/JM$ is the vector space? Did it follow from the facts that $M\otimes_R R/J\simeq M/JM$ and $R/J$ is the field?

Comment: @user I think so.

Comment: @user26857 Does there exist any statement that say that for $R$ is a (commutative if necessary) ring, $M$ is a $R$-module, $F$ is a field then $M\otimes_R F$ is a vector space over $F$?

Comment: @user Yes, of course. Even more general, if $F$ is another ring then the tensor product is an $F$-module.

Comment: If $F$ is supposed to a ring, what is the relationship between $F$ and $R$ mentioned above so that the tensor product becomes $F$-module?

Comment: @user $F$ can be any $R$-algebra.

Comment: @user26857 Ok I see. Thanks for kindly answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the non-local case:

$\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ is generated by $1\otimes 1$. So, we just have to prove that $1\otimes 1=0$.

As $(m,n)=1$, by Bezout, there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $am+bn=1$. Then

$$1\otimes1=(am+bn)\otimes1= am\otimes1 + bn\otimes 1 = 0 + b\otimes n = 0.$$