# $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ if and only if $\Omega_{\overline{B}/k}=0$, where $\overline{B}=B\otimes_A k$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $A$ be a local ring with residue field $k$. Let $B$ be an $A$-algebra such that $B$ is finitely generated as $A$-module. Let $\overline{B}:=B \otimes_A k$. Prove that $\overline{B}$ is non zero and that $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ if and only if $\Omega_{\overline{B}/k}=0$.

The fact that $\overline{B}$ is non zero holds true because it is an Artinian algebra, hence it is product of local Artin rings which are non zero. I would use the Nakayama's Lemma to prove that equivalence, but i don't know how to do it.

Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change of basis for Kahler differentials tells you that
$$\Omega_{(B\otimes_A k)/k}\cong k \otimes_A \Omega_{B/A}.$$
So you get the implication $\Omega_{B/A}=0\implies \Omega_{\overline{B}/A}=0.$

For the converse one you should use [Nakayama's lemma in this spirit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321374/tensor-product-of-two-finitely-generated-modules-over-a-local-ring-is-zero). Since $B$ is finitely generated $A$-module, then $\Omega_{B/A}$ is finitely generated $A$-module as well. Hence, from the above formula and Nakayam's lemma you get the converse implication.

Comment: In fact i put in the hypothesis that B is a finitely generated A-module and so also $\Omega_{B/A}$ is finitely generated as an A-module.

Comment: My misread. I will fix it in a moment

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me where to find base change of kahler differentials?

Comment: @Francesco For instance Eisenbud, Commutative algebra Proposition 16.4 from Section 16.3

Comment: Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Francesco Easier you have it here at Lemma 10.130.12
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM

Comment: Perfect, really appreciated!