If a perfect complex is zero when derived restricted to every fibre, is it zero?
Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a perfect complex of $A$-modules. If for every field $k$ with a ring map $A \rightarrow k$ we know $M \otimes^L_A k = 0$ then can we conclude $M = 0$? And if not, what sort of conditions do we need on $A$ and $M$ for it to be true?

Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321374/tensor-product-of-two-finitely-generated-modules-over-a-local-ring-is-zero

Yes.
Without loss of generality (choosing a minimal length complex and shifting),
$$M=\cdots\to0\to P_n\to P_{n-1}\to\cdots\to P_1\xrightarrow{d_1}P_0\to0\to\cdots,$$
where the $P_i$ are finitely generated projective modules and $d_1$ is not surjective.
Since $P_0$ is finitely generated, $\operatorname{im}d_1$ is contained in a maximal submodule $X$ of $P_0$. So $P_0/X$ is a simple $A$-module, and hence isomorphic to some quotient field $k$ of $A$.
By right exactness of tensor products, the degree zero homology of $M\otimes_A k$ is isomorphic to $(P_0/\operatorname{im}d_1)\otimes_Ak$, which has $k\otimes_Ak\cong k$ as a quotient, and is therefore nonzero.

Perfect answer, thank you so much!
